# UIAutomator cannot read some content description in Facebook's app UI elements

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I have a problem with an application that uses UI Automator to perform some operations on the Facebook application.
I realized that on some phones UI Automator is able to read all the content descriptions (where present) of the UI elements while on other phones it would seem not to be able to.

I give an example using UI Automator Viewer.

**Phone 1:** UI Automator accesses and correctly reads the content description of the elements highlighted in red.

Working, can read content descriptions:

[image]

**Phone 2:** Ui Automator fails to read the same content descriptions for some reason (while for example TalkBack is able to read them, so content description sare present).
Please note that UI Automator does not fail to read all the content descriptions **but only a few.**

Not working, cannot read content descriptions:

[image]

Phone 1 has Android 9 while Phone 2 Android 10 but I don't think this is the discriminating factor as I tried on another phone with Android 9 and the same problem occurs, I have the doubt that it could be a permissions problem or something similar.
Both phones are running the same version of the Facebook application and are not rooted.

Thank you for the support.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply.
You only need the UIAutomatorViewer in order to try to reproduce the problem,
This tool comes with the SDK as long as I can remember.